# Translating "reclaim" (in the context of linguistic social movements)

Tags: translation

I am drafting an article about reclaiming "他" as a gender-inclusive pronoun. I wonder what "reclaim" could be translated into.

Some translations that I have found via online translation utilities and dictionaries include the following:

- "重拾"
- "挽回"
- "重新定义" (too long, leading to bad rhythm; "定义" presupposes prescriptive instead of descriptive linguistic context)
- "讨回" (has connotation of begging, may be self-patronizing)
- "要求归还" (grammatically awkward; missing noun)
- "夺回" (too aggressive)

(The linguistics of the "他" pronoun itself is outside of the scope of this question.)

Answer (score 1):

Not a 1:1 direct translation, but how about "恢复" (restore) or "回归" (return)?

让
"他"
**回归** (return to) / **恢复** (restore)
其 (its)
性别包容 (gender-inclusive)
的
本义 (original meaning)

IMO, this is a more natural way to express what you mean.

Comment: Since "recover" is very close to"reclaim", I think "恢复" is a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure of your facts? Did “他”previously hold this sway? Do you have any evidence of this?

In ancient ancient times there was only one pronoun: "he."
从前只有一个代词：“他”。

Nowadays, we use three pronouns "he, she, it."
现在我们有“他，她和它”三个代词。

重申：再次申述：reaffirm ; reiterate ; repeat ; renew ; restate ; reassert

I am just writing an article about reclaiming " 他" as a general purpose pronoun.
我正在写一篇关于重申“他”作为代词统称的文章。

Comment: IIRC from school, 他 was gender-inclusive before the New Culture Movement when 刘半农 introduced 她. See also: [刘半农与“她”的故事](https://web.archive.org/web/20180929085032/http://www.gmw.cn/content/2004-07/20/content_60982.htm) and [A Cultural History of the Chinese Character “Ta (She)”—On the invention and identification of a new female pronoun](https://www.harvard-yenching.org/research/cultural-history-of-the-chinese-character-ta/)

Comment: Extremely interesting! The Chinese were motivated by a twentieth century desire to emulate English? Old English had: he, heo, hit = he,she,it,. she derives from Old English seo, the feminine Nominative of 'that'. The masculine 'that', se gave us Modern English 'the'. Still to explain is why 他人 means "other people". And, of course, why gender would be important!